# what's the different System.IO.Pipes namespace and System.IO.Pipelines namespace

Tags: system.io.pipelines

what's the different in the System.IO.Pipes namespace and System.IO.Pipelines namespace class.
So what's case for System.IO.Pipes and what's case for System.IO.Pipelines.

I'm confused with the System.IO.Pipes namespace and System.IO.Pipelines,because there have some common class name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### [System.IO.Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes)

> Contains types that provide a means for interprocess communication through anonymous and/or named pipes.

This is provided as part of the .NET libraries. It's for IPC.

### [System.IO.Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines)

> System.IO.Pipelines is a library that is designed to make it easier to do high-performance I/O in .NET. It's a library targeting .NET Standard that works on all .NET implementations.
>
> #### What problem does System.IO.Pipelines solve
>
> Apps that parse streaming data are composed of boilerplate code having many specialized and unusual code flows. The boilerplate and special case code is complex and difficult to maintain.
>
> System.IO.Pipelines was architected to:
>
> - Have high performance parsing streaming data.
> - Reduce code complexity.

This is made available separately as a NuGet package. It's a high performance IO library (writing files, parsing strings, etc.).